# Flashing firmware using RPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, firmware

I have been trying to flash firmware onto the PC Engines APU2 platform. I'm using an SPI interface. RPi3's SPI is hooked up to the three-state quad buffer SN74LV125AD. For now, it is just a proof of concept. But when I do flashing, I get an error like that

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ flashrom -w apu2_v4.8.0.3.rom -p linux_spi:dev=/dev/spidev0.0,spispeed=8000
flashrom v0.9.9-r1954 on Linux 4.14.50-v7+ (armv7l)
flashrom is free software, get the source code at https://flashrom.org

Calibrating delay loop... OK.
Found Generic flash chip "unknown SPI chip (RDID)" (0 kB, SPI) on linux_spi.
===
This flash part has status NOT WORKING for operations: PROBE READ ERASE WRITE
The test status of this chip may have been updated in the latest development
version of flashrom. If you are running the latest development version,
please email a report to flashrom@flashrom.org if any of the above operations
work correctly for you with this flash chip. Please include the flashrom log
file for all operations you tested (see the man page for details), and mention
which mainboard or programmer you tested in the subject line.
Thanks for your help!
Read is not working on this chip. Aborting.
```

I was trying to increase or decrease speed, but it doesn't solve the problem. Generally, the Raspberry Pi can't find the APU2 when using the buffer. For now, I use the buffer in THT package and all is hooked up on a breadboard. Thus, I use 2 IDC cables.

Where I'm making a mistake. Can length of the wires be a cause of why flashing doesn't work?

Comment: How do you have the buffer wired up? Three of the SPI signals are outputs from the SPI master (the RPi) -- CLK, MOSI and SS -- while the fourth signal is an input -- MISO. You need to take this into account when wiring up the buffers.

Comment: From the side of the master CLK, MOSI and SS are connected to the inputs of the buffers, while MISO is connected to the output